# Can't set a EntityBase for webservice function

Tags: web-services, soap, lotusscript

I'm trying to consume a web service written in .net.

Main function needs a class with different data types.

```
Function ClCardSend(key As XSD_STRING, ERP_CLCard_ As ERP_CLCard_n10, CLCardRef As Long_Holder, _
ErrorMessage As XSD_STRING_Holder) As Boolean

    Let ClCardSend = Service.Invoke("ClCardSend", key, ERP_CLCard_, CLCardRef, ErrorMessage)

End Function
```

This is the class

```
Class ERP_CLCard_n10 As EntityBase_n10 

    Public IsInserted As Boolean
    Public id_Ref_Status As Long
    Public id_ERP_CLCardStatus As Long
    Public id_ERP_CLCardFicheType As Long
    Public id_ERP_CLCard As Long
    Public strCode As XSD_STRING
    Public strTitle As XSD_STRING
```

.....
        Public strClientAuthorizedNameSureName As XSD_STRING
        Public strClientEmailAddress As XSD_STRING
        Public ERP_LOGICALREF As Long
        Public ERP_FICHENO As XSD_STRING
        Public intFirmNr As Long
        Public intPeriodNr As Long

```
    Sub NEW
    End Sub
```

And this is the snippet which i call the function

```
Dim ERP_CLCard_  As Erp_clcard_n10
Dim CLCardRef As New Long_holder

With ERP_CLCard_

    .Id_erp_clcard = 0
    .id_Ref_Status = 1      '1:Aktif, 2:Pasif
    .id_ERP_CLCardStatus=1  'Default 1 Edilecek
    .id_ERP_CLCardFicheType = 1 '1:Alıcı, 2:Satıcı, 3:Alıcı+Satıcı
    .strCode.Setvaluefromstring("TEST")
    .strTitle.Setvaluefromstring("TEST")   
    .strSpeCode.Setvaluefromstring("000")      
    .strSpeCode2.Setvaluefromstring("strSpeCode2")  
    .strSpeCode3.Setvaluefromstring("strSpeCode3")    
    .strSpeCode4.Setvaluefromstring("strSpeCode4")    
    .strSpeCode5.Setvaluefromstring("strSpeCode5")     
    .strCyphCode.Setvaluefromstring(vUID(0))    
    .strProjectCode.Setvaluefromstring("strProjectCode")  
End With

a = ERP_CLCard_.strProjectCode.Getvalueasstring()

MsgBox a

Call stub.Clcardsend(API_KEY, ERP_CLCard_, CLCardRef,sErrorMessage)
```

When i send, other end receives my class as null. And i can't access the properties of my class on debug.